# Typecasting gives ClassCast Exception in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have written a code where I am setting values in a `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap` as `java.lang.Object`.

I did this so that I could put a variety of types as values. The values are of the proper type when I set them in a function. When I try to retrieve them though I am getting a classcast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Here are bits and pieces of the relevant code

```
     def readInputTexts() : HashMap[String,Object] =
  {
    var ioStrings : HashMap[String,Object] = new HashMap[String,Object]();
    val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOp));
    val bwIp1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileIp1));
    val bwIp2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileIp2));
    val iterator1 = Iterator.continually(bwIp1.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
    var input1 : String = "";
    var similarityCount: Integer = 0;

    for(str1 <- iterator1)
    {
      input1 += (str1);
    }
        ioStrings.put("ip1", input1) ;

    val iterator2 = Iterator.continually(bwIp2.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
    var input2 : String = "";
    for(str2 <- iterator2)
    {
      input2 += (str2);
    }
   ioStrings.put("ip2", input2) ;


     ioStrings.put("op", bw) ;
       bwIp1.close();
       bwIp2.close();   
       ioStrings;   
      }
```

Here is the code for retrieving the values

```
var inputOutputMap : HashMap[String, Object] = new HashMap[String, Object]();
inputOutputMap = inputOutput.readInputTexts();
val bw = inputOutputMap.get("op");
var input1 = inputOutputMap.get("ip1").asInstanceOf[String];
var similarityCount: Integer = 0;
var input2  = inputOutputMap.get("ip2").asInstanceOf[String];
```

I am new to scala and would appreciate it if someone points me in the right direction to resolve this..

Comment: why the down vote??

Comment: Why is your map `ioStrings` a `HashMap[String, Object]` instead of a `HashMap[String, String]`? If you'd use the latter, then casting would not be necessary. You should try to avoid casting as much as possible, because it defeats type safety.

Comment: Also, semicolons are not necessary in Scala.

Comment: semicolons are just a java habit. I want other types in the map, hence the Object @Jesper

Answer (score -1):

Solved it..
Scala returns values in Option[Value] rather than the value itself. Hence Option was not getting tyoecasted to String.

I changed the code

```
var input1 = inputOutputMap.get("ip1").asInstanceOf[String];
```

to

```
var input1 = inputOutputMap("ip1").asInstanceOf[String];
```

thats it. Seems trivial now. But when one is stuck seems really puzzling;))